# Texture Node in the cycle render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, makehuman

I am working  on cycle render using MakeHuman model. On MakeHuman , model has some texture images.  I remark for example when I do a person with t-shirt that there is two images shirt_normals.png and shirt_texture.png. In the Node mode, I rely these images as mentioned in the below image. What is the difference between these images? And is my work is correct? Because, I could not remark any effect of the shirt_normals.png  image.
[image]

Comment: Did you UV unwrap it?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise,Yes I did. I edit my image.

Comment: You have to attach the texture to both images...

Comment: You mean *Nodes*? ^^

Comment: @GiantCowFilms, Yes I did. I edit my image.

Answer (score 1):

The texture (usually called a *diffuse* map) simply affects the color of the object.  The *normal* map affects the [normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21190/what-are-face-normals) to create a bump-mapping effect.  This works by converting the red and green channels of the normal map to x and y (or y and x, I forget which) rotation of the surface normals (`0.5` being straight up, or no change) to simulate small bumps and surface details for added realism.  (The blue channel is actually ignored, though it is usually set at `0.5` as well which makes for the distinctive pinkish/bluish color of a normal map.)

As for your setup, you have two problems:

1. You need to send the normal map through the *color* input of a *vector > normal map* node and the *normal* output of that to the *normal* input of the shaders.
2. You are giving the normal map normals as [mapping coordinates](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23174/5705), all texture maps should have the same mapping coordinates.  In this case it looks like you are using *generated* for the diffuse so you should use generated coordinates for the normal map as well.

[image]
<sub>Credit to [@Vladimir](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/16443/5705) for image, this is a croped version of his screenshot as I don't have Blender available at the moment.</sub>

Comment: Could you put an image?

Comment: @startingBlender I am on my tablet now, so I don't have Blender available to take a screenshot.  But if you give me a couple minutes I can probably find one on the web! :D

Comment: Did you mean like that? (I edited my image)

Comment: @startingBlender Sorry, but I don't see any difference.  Did you upload the right image?

Comment: @Vladimir If you don't want me to use your screenshot feel free to remove it.

Comment: @startingBlender I added a screenshot.

Comment: I remark that UVMap did not appear in the Normal Map.

Comment: @startingBlender If your mesh is unwrapped then you choose the appropriate uv map in that slot, otherwise leave it blank.