# Getting a normal map to work in a multiple uv node setup

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, node-editor

The setup is not that complex, it has the typical stuff for color, normal, ambient occlusion and specularity maps.
Problem is that there are multiple UV maps, and some of them overlap each other, f.e. the sand overlaps the mountain uv map.

So I try to figure out a) how to limit some of these texture maps properly to separate uvs and b) how to get the normal map to work.

---

Here is the node setup for the mountain(*Gebirge means mountain*):
[image: Mountain nodes]

1. Notice how I tried to limit all of the image textures with an attribute to the mountain(the uv map is called like the attribute), I didnt use the UV map node it is just still there.
2. Notice how I tried to limit the Diffuse and Glossy Shaders to the mountain with the output of the normal map node. This does have an effect, I still don't know if it is correct like this and I don't know if there will be problems with the other textures/UV maps.
3. Notice how the normal map is set up, it doesnt work like this.

---

Now here is a picture of the mountain, don't mind the red spots on the stuff which is not mountain, it's part of its uv map:
[image: Mountain Pic]

---

Last but not least this is the kind of node setup I want to use to show other textures (of sand and stuff) on other UV maps but all in the same material:
[image: other stuff]

---

I'd love if someone could maybe give me some live support with this. Like chat or skype, I send you the .blend file plus the textures and stuff.
Just send me a PM or chat invite.

---

EDIT: Now the normal map works with the solution that MrZak provided:
[image: normal map works]

But there is still the problem with the other areas being influenced by the **Glossy** and probably the **Diffuse** Shader too. You can see this at the red tinting of the beach cause by the slightly red glossy shader.

I tried the **attribute** and the **uv map** node but they wont restrict it to the UV map of the mountain.

You could comment on this if you have a solution but I'll probably post a new question for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what happens with beach but there're several problems.

1. Don't plug output of the **Normal map** into the Displacement input, see [this very good answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16443/using-a-normal-map-together-with-a-bump-map) for more info. In your case it may be enough to use only normal maps.
2. Consider plugging image into the **Normal Map** node if it's the result of processing with using [some programs](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?188339-Program-to-create-normal-maps) where the result is image of purple color. Otherwise plug it into the **Bump** node instead (the link above again can be helpful).
3. (less important) Why not using **UV Map** node and **Attribute** one instead ?
4. Regarding to UV maps I think it's better to search for some questions here or to ask new one (as it seems to be arranging and managing the UV maps). Basically you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to average islands' scale and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to make them fit in the texture space (pack them); but the exact way depends on situation, it may be needed to use some other tricks like stitching etc.

   You may want to read about [normal maps, how to and how not to bake normal maps and a lot more](http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/textures/how-not-to-make-normal-maps-from-photos-or-images.php)

   See [wiki article](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/mapping/uv/unwrapping.html?highlight=unwrap) for more info on creating, editing and managing UV maps.

Comment: Thank you once again Mr Zak for taking the time to give a noob like me some advice. I'll check out all of the links and go through this and tell you if it worked afterwards.

Comment: Normal map works now, Yay!