# Normal map appear dark without details cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

I retopo my high poly sculpt, created UV map, selected the high poly object first, than the low poly (so the low poly is the active one), bake normal map (cycles used, so I had a texture image node selected), than apply normal map as in picture:
[image]

this is how appear the low poly models without normal map (note normal map texture node muted)

As you can see when apply normal map the model turn black, without details. I tried to add a texture coordinate node, on UV, as suggested on here ([Object turns dark when using normal map in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48958/object-turns-dark-when-using-normal-map-in-cycles)), but don't work.

not only the model turn very dark but need very strong light to illuminate it.

Maybe I doing something wrong with normal map creation? Anyway the map is here.

Thanks if advance for your help and sorry for my poor enghlish.

EDIT: SOLVED! I didn't change anything, open the some file made me crazy for an entire week and boom! It work, all details are here, normal map work correctly. Cannot understood why or what happened

Comment: Check if you have "Non color data" selected in normal map texture node and set lower "strength" in Normal map node. If this don't help you, consider uploading .blend file. We can only guess now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If you look texture node  is set to non  colour data, the file is for a client, part of bigger eork, I don't know if I can share

Comment: Try lowering effect of the normal map in the Normal map node. 10 is really much and blackish effects like that could be result of that.

Comment: Thanks Mr Zak, tried even this, lowering normal map node help a lot light, but zero details on the surface.

Comment: @Rosalinda - sorry, I missed nose setup. What about strenght? 10 is too much i thing. I usually work with numbers lower than 1, sometimes around 3. BTW: Did you save normal map before rendering? I thing nodes load data from files on disc, not from blender cache, so must be saved first.

Comment: Shubol3d@ yes, I tried lowering, the only thing I obtain is less dark surface, but not details. Yes, I saved the normal map

Comment: Mr Zak, this is the mehs I unwrapped for normal map. I retopologyze the high poly model, obtain this mesh, generate UV, then, in cycles, select the high poly, than the low poly model, and baked normal, I obtain this normal map (don't know if is OK or not, I learning now normal mapping and texture in general).

Comment: I see, it has UV map selected in Normal map node. Hard to tell more about that without a file (you could create simple mesh and use the same procedure as you did and [upload](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) *that*, however that can take some time). Check maybe [normals](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3606/1245) in both high and low poly meshes, although I don't think that's problem.

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?

Comment: Hi, I'll upload tomorrow, thanks for all your comments

Comment: @Shubol3D Add a link where you can download the blender scene and map already baked (report again here http://www.mediafire.com/download/bl0aaetjm00pxfp/Normal_map_problem%282%29.zip Again, thanks in advance for your time

Comment: SOLVED! I didn't change anything, open the some file made me crazy for an entire week and boom! It work, all details are here, normal map work correctly. Cannot understood why or what happened. Thanks to all for your time.