# Transparent objects passing through causes a shadow

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, transparency

My scene contains transparent objects that pass through each other during the  animation but it seems to be casting a shadow when the overlap

I've attached a screenshot if anyone can help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Although that isn't exactly related, do not plug output from Normal Map node into *Displacement* input socket of Output node; use *Normal* input socket of Diffuse node instead. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16443/using-a-normal-map-together-with-a-bump-map

Comment: you can always just turn off cast shadow in the object menu, and animate that too

Comment: that looks to me like overlapping geometry and errors produced by Z-fighting, but without access to the file is hard to tell what the issue is.

Comment: are you sure this is caused by the transparent objects? does the artifact disappear when you hide them on a layer which is not being rendered?

Comment: That's [z-fighting](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21/5705), not a shadow.  You have some overlapping geometry there.

Answer (score 0):

Use this node setup to disable cast shadows:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, its still doing the same thing. I have updated my question with a screenshot of my node setup if thats helps